# Android Studio problem stuck loading in view

Tags: android

[Can anyone please help me what's the problem. I tried reinstalling it and still not fixed the view mode is stuck loading and all of my layouts are red (0 errors)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCmkb.png)

Reinstall it and still nothing happened I hope someone will help me thank you

Comment: Please helppppp